# Injective: In what circumstances would there be less than one pre-image of an image?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to get my head around the different types of function in set theory. In the definition of injective where:

if (x',y) is in f and (x'',y) is in f, then x'= x''

in other words y has no more than one pre-image, and therefore implying that it is possible for there to be an image with less than one pre-image.

Therefore does injection allow the following circumstances:

1. 2y = f(x)
2. y = f(x)

Comment: No, no - of course an "image with less than one (ie, zero) pre-image" is a contradiction, that can never happen. An injective function has no more than one pre-image for each image, but the opposite of "no more than one" isn't "less than one", it's "only one".

Comment: @ Jack M In what sense does injective differ with respect to surjective function which has "y has at least one pre-image"?

Comment: @Will: For non-surjective functions, there will be elements of a *codomain* which have no preimages. There will **never** be elements of the *range* which have no preimages.

Comment: @Carmeron Buie: I thought codomain and range were the same! After an internet search co-domain may include elements which are not function specific?

Comment: Yes, codomain and range of a function need not be the same but by definition, we always have "Range$~\subseteq~$Codomain". In the case that they are equal, the function is said to be onto (surjective).